# Facebook Comments Shortcode with Post ID

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, comments

I am using a wordpress template for Music Promotion and trying to connect facebook comments plugin via "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/" ... I understood all the steps and successfully connected by the shortcode with browser.. Here is the single album page where the comment plugin shows after the listed songs... "http://shanmp3.net/?download=sai-aung-htee-kham&lang=en"

```html
HERE IS THE SHORTCODE I AM USING FOR FACEBOOK COMMENTS IN MY SINGLE-CONTENT-PAGE.PHP
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.shanmp3.net" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

**ACTUAL PROBLEM** 
When I comment on any post it not working as unique and showing the same comment on all the post as I am using "PHP" Single Content Page so I am unable to write a proper code as

```html
<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->id)); ?>
```

which work unique for each Post.

I appreciate if you provide me the correct PHP Code as per Post ID which work unique for each post.

Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

Alright I have just sorted out myself and its very simple as you just need to replace :

```html
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="mydomain.com" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

mydomain.com with PHP the_permalink as the following:

```html
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-numposts="5"></div>
```